# Non singleton service for angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular component that is reused multiple time in the same page.

The angular component is dependent on a service, since it is reused multiple times, I would like to have a new instance of a service for each component, is that possible? Or do I have to use a for loop and create a separate object inside the service for each component to achieve the same effect?

Edit: I am using angular 1

Comment: If you are using AngularJS, please remove the Angular tag, those are different things.

Comment: but, do you want to share some data with the service?. If not then you can use simple a clase that acts as a service, and create the instance of that class inside your component.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a factory (instead of a service) which returns a function to which you can even provide some data (think of it as a constructor).

```js
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('MyFactory', MyFactory);


function MyFactory() {

    return (someOptions) => ({
        myProperty: someOptions.myProperty,
        myMethod: () => {
            // ...
        }
    });

}
```

You can than use it in your controller like so. Every time you call `MyFactory({ ... })` a new separate "instance" will be created.

```js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);


function MyController(MyFactory) {

    const myFactoryObj = MyFactory({ myProperty: 'test' });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that service in each of your components as DI and then call that service to create a new instance every time. You can also set `'cache':true` in your function so that you don't make multiple api calls for the same data. (Only for 'GET' method). Does that clarify your doubt?